# ruby convert string to int without using 'to_i'

Tags: ruby, class, rspec

So I'm defining a anonymous class to test a method like so:

```
  let!(:s_integer) do
    class << self
      def change(value)
        self(value)
      end
    end

    def change(value)
      self.class.change(value)
    end
  end
```

The problem is that where `Integer('9')` works, `self('9')` doesn't, but I can't use `to_i` so how do I work around this problem?

Comment: `Integer('9')` works because there is a method called `Integer` defined in the `Kernel` module: `method(:Integer).owner #=> Kernel`

Comment: @MichaelKohl: sometimes I wish those methods didn't exist. They cause more problems than they solve :)

Comment: I'm happy they do. `Integer()` is still the best way to parse any input into a valid and *sensible* number. Unless of course you're of the school that thinks `'foo'.to_i #=> 0` is sensible ;-)

Comment: I'm super aware this is a really strange thing but I have to do it this way to test the method. Either this Or writing a whole class,  I think I'll just have to write a class and use that as it seems like it would be simpler in the end than what I'm trying at the moment.

Comment: @MichaelKohl it's just confusing to have uppercase method names which also happen to be class names. `Integer.parse` would have been a much better choice.

Comment: @Thermatix why do you think you have to approach it this way? What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: It doesn't really matter any more as I'm trying a different approach.

Comment: @Stefan Ruby is full of idiosyncrasies like this ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ For example `Integer` doesn't have `.try_convert` like `String`, `Hash` or `Array` do, though all of them have corresponding implicit conversion methods (`to_str`, `to_hash`, `to_ary`, `to_int`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Integer(arg, base=0)` is a method in `Kernel`, not in `Integer`. So you can't use `self` to call it.

```
def change(value)
  Integer(value)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, if this is the only way then I'll have to try somthing else as I need to return the same anonymous class. Still now I know definitively.